# most of redirects silently lost using "meta redirect"

Tags: java, http, nginx

We have a Java WEB server accepting requests from a third-party platform. All requests are http redirects.

If redirected by 302 ,all is ok. But if redirecting with meta refresh, a large portion of the redirects are missing.

All of the requests are initiated from mobile phone.

I have no idea why this could happen.

Our Server is behind a nginx, all deployed on aws.

Answer (score 0):

`302 Found` is an [HTTP *protocol*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) *level* redirect.

HTML ["meta refreshes"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-http-equiv) are only (potentially) processed by browsers that read, understand, and implement HTML.  If a non-browser client receives a `200 OK` response containing an HTML payload, it might not know to look for a meta directive.